# Equivalence relation on the set of word.

Tags: abstract-algebra

my question is about how the associative product $∗$ ( concatenation ) induces a group structure on the set of words $\mathcal M$$(X)$ in a set $X$.
I found this on an online course : 
the idea is to define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal M$$(X)$, the lowest which allows us to say that $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$ are equivalent to the empty word.

Let me explain :
In $\mathcal M$$(X)$, we do not even have that $ x * x ^ {- 1} = ∅ $ where $∅$ is the empty word; reverse elements of $ X $ are only formal.
So that each element has an inverse, we must take equivalence classes, according to a certain relation of equivalence. Since we obviously wants formal inverses of elements of $ X $ become true inverses, he'll have $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$ are equivalents to the empty word and by extension the words $s_1 · · · s_kxx^{-1}s_{k+1} · · · s_n$ and $s_1 · · · s_kx^{-1}xs_{k+1} · · · s_n$ are both equivalent to $s_1 · · · · · · s_n$. We will call deletion or insertion of $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$
an elementary modification. We say that two words $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ in $\mathcal M$$(X)$ are equivalents, denoted $\omega_1$ $\sim$ $\omega_2$ if and only if there exists a finite chain of elementary modifications connecting $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. In other words, we take the smallest equivalence relation that allows us to say that $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$ are equivalent to the empty word.

My question is how to define such equivalence relation ? in other words, what is the sufficient and necessary condition for two words to be equivalent.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Very brief sketch: If you have a word, you can look for factors of the form $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$ and remove them. Do this until there are none of them left anymore. Show (using Newman's lemma, for example) that the resulting word does not depend on the order in which you got rid of those factors. Now, conclude that every equivalence class contains exactly one *normalized* word (where "normalized" means that it contains no $xx^{-1}$ or $x^{-1}x$ factors). But I suspect that better writeups should be contained in standard texts...

Comment: Actually here's my argument in detail: https://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/990s08/public/myasnikov.1.free.groups.pdf . There are other arguments too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a simpler way to describe the equivalence relation than "if and only if there exists a finite chain of elementary modifications connecting [them]." That is the sufficient and necessary condition.

Comment: Can you please define what is a " chain of elementary modifications" connecting two chains ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the standard terminology here would be, but you could say for example that $\omega_1\sim\omega_n$ are 'simply connected' if they differ by an insertion or deletion of a term $xx^{-1}$. Then you can call them 'chain connected' denoted $\omega_1\cong \omega_n$ if there is a sequence of words $\omega_1\sim\omega_2\sim...\sim\omega_n$. Chain connectivity is then the equivalence relation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Apparently I was not looking for a condition , it was before my eyes, I was looking for more of an explanation of this condition.